# Is there a stable Unity release for linux?

Tags: unity, linux, release

I am doing some machine learning and need to run unity on linux but didn't come across the stable release, if anyone is working on unity on linux, please point me towards a stable release.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackExchange Q&A isn't well-suited to keeping up with changes in software versions. For time-sensitive information about a particular piece of software, please consult the manufacturer's site & support channels.

Answer (score 2):

No. At this time the Unity site still refers to the Linux editor as an "experimental" Beta feature. There is not a stable release. [The latest Linux builds, release notes, and known issues are documented in this Unity forum thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/page-2#post-3481193).

In future, please direct this type of software query to the makers of that software. Because it's time-sensitive (maybe in two months there *will* be a stable Linux build released), handling it through our Q&A here risks leaving misleading signposts for future users.

> (So, if you're a future user reading this after May 2018: don't take my word for it — check the manufacturer's website for the most up to date information)